# Radio Button "Select" Toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to make a very very simple script that checks to see if a certain radio button option is clicked, and if so, shows another set of fields (this works fine), but if you unselect that radio button option, it hides the extra set of fields (seemingly simple, but does not work for me!)

Also I am newish to JS/JQuery so debugging this has been a struggle! Thanks for any help :)

My HTML radio button that triggers the fields display - imagine there are 6 other radio button options with this (each classed with [class="otherFund"]).

```
<input type="radio" name="ItemName1" id="Relief1" value="Daughters of Penelope Charitable Relief Fund" onclick="set_item('DOP-Relief-Fund', 8)" onchange="relief_fund_handler()" />
```

Here is the text and field and I want to toggle with the above button's selection

```
<p id="Earmark1" style="display: none;">
   <strong>Please designate below what relief fund you would like your <em>DOP Charitable Relief</em> donation to go towards (see bulleted examples above).</strong><br />
   <strong>Earmarked for <span class="required">*</span>:</strong><input type="text" name="Earmark1" id="Earmark1" size="50" />
</p>
```

And here are my JS attempts...

*Attempt 1:*

```
function relief_fund_handler() {

   var relief_elem = document.getElementById("Relief1"),
       earmark_elem = document.getElementById("Earmark1"),
       donate_elem = document.getElementById("ItemName1");

   if (relief_elem.checked) {
       earmark_elem.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;");    
   } else if (".otherFund".checked) {          
       earmark_elem.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
   }
}
```

*attempt 2:*

```
function relief_fund_handler() {

   var relief_elem = document.getElementById("Relief1"),
       earmark_elem = document.getElementById("Earmark1"),
       donate_elem = document.getElementById("ItemName1");

   if (relief_elem.checked) {  
       earmark_elem.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;");    
   } else {
       earmark_elem.setAttribute("style", "display: none;"); 
   }
}
```

*attempt 3:*

```
$("#Relief1:checked")( 
    function() { 
       $('#Earmark1').toggle();
    } 
);
```

On attempt #3, I have also replaced the `:checked` with `.click`, `.select`, `.change` and none have worked... Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you're already using jQuery, this is simple as using `.show()` and `.hide()`:

```
$('#Relief1').on('change',function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#Earmark1').show();
  } else {
    $('#Earmark1').hide();
  }
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4meB/

also note, don't use duplicate ID's, they are meant to be unique (in this case, you have a dulpicate `#Earmark1` for the p tag and span). Also, in the example fiddle, I changed it to a checkbox instead of a radio since You can't uncheck a radio if there is only one option.

Comment: That's great except you changed the OP's code from radio buttons to a single checkbox. Did you miss the part that said "imagine there are 6 other radio button options"?

Comment: @j08691 yes, I stated that in the note at the bottom. that was just for the sake of an example since you can't toggle just one radio.

Comment: He doesn't have just one radio.

Comment: he can easily apply this to all other radio buttons. it's just an example on how to show/hide an element given an input.

Comment: @kennypu Instead of changing from radio to checkbox..Why not just add a second radio button to your example so you that you can toggle?

Comment: @RandomWebGuy that's true, but that is nothing to nit pick or stress about. an example is an example.

Comment: @kennypu It's not nit picking because your example is flawed. Changing the input to radio and adding a second one breaks the example you provided. See this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/k2xJ6/ The text doesn't disappear when you select the second radio button. Which I believe was the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input.otherFund").change(function() {
    $('#Earmark1').toggle($(this).attr('id') == 'Relief1');
});​
```

Comment: This solution is far better than mine and I'll be putting this in my memory for another day, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all of the events off of the radio button like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="ItemName1" id="Relief1" value="Daughters of Penelope Charitable Relief Fund" />
```

And using the following jquery script:

```
​$(function(){
    $("#Relief1").change(function(){
        $(this).is(":checked") ? $("#Earmark1").show() : $("#Earmark1").hide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each radio button and assign an event handler to each radio button, so when selected it shows the other fields and when deselected it hides the other fields.  The code below may help you arrive at the correct answer.

```
// Iterate the radio buttons and assign an event listener

$('input[name="ItemName1"]').each( function() {

    // Click Handler

    $(this).live('click', function() {

        // Check for selected

        if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
        {
            $('#EarMark1').show();
        }
        else 
        {
            $('#EarMark1').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

It's not perfect, nor is it the most elegant solution.  With some tweaking it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

thank you to everyone!!! I ended up using kennypu's example - the ":checked" seemed to work fine even though it is a radio button. I had to make some tweaks to it, and ended up with 2 separate functions instead of the "else". For some reason the other examples were not working for me - although I highly doubt it has to do with your code, and likely has to do with other things going on in the page. Since we're using an external form/database handler, we need to keep the events and other code there.

Here's what ended up working..

```
    $(function(){
    $("#Relief1").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#Earmark1").show();
      }
      });
    });

  $(function(){
    $("#Radio1, #Radio2, #Radio3, #Radio4, #Radio5, #Radio6, #Radio7").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#Earmark1").hide();
      }
      });
    });
```

Pretty clunky, but I got it to work how I needed. Thank you to everyone who contributed, it helped quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<script>
var r=$('input[name="ItemName1"]).is(:checked);
if(r)
{
alert("Item is checked");//replace with any code
}
</script>
```

Comment: @j08691 This will identify which radio buttom is selected. All that remains is to replace alert with users own code.